# How can be mathematically formulated the condition "$x$ is away from each point of singularity"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, singularity

During the math class of today, we introduced the function
$$f(x)=\frac1x, $$
which has a singularity at $x=0$. Since for certain computations it was needed to avoid the singularity, we said something like: "In order to avoid the point $x=0$, suppose to stay away from it assuming, e.g. that $|x|>>0$ or also $x\to +\infty.$"

This is clear for me, but I have a question: If we deal with a function with an infinite set of singularities (points), how it can be reformulated the above idea to avoid each point of singularity?

I am thinking, for example, to a function like
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin x}.$$
I think it maybe would be something related to a choice of a suitable $\varepsilon>0$ enough small such that we can consider $x$ when outside the neighborhood of radius $\varepsilon$ and the neighborhood of each singularity never intersect. But actually I am not sure about that.

Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "such that we can consider $x$ when outside the neighborhood of radius $\epsilon$ and the neighborhood of each singularity never intersect"? What is this supposed to say? Are you looking for a general statement? Just figure out what a "bad point" is, put all them "bad points" into a set, say $U$, and then consider $x\in \mathbb R\setminus U$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor in this case, $U$ would be open/closed? And what about $\mathbb{R}\setminus U$? Is closed/open? I was looking for a general statement as Golden_Ratio provided in her/his answer for the particular case of my example.

Comment: You have not bothered to describe what a "general case" would be, and thats not surprising because who knows how to pin such a thing down.  It is not productive in analysis to ask for statements that are too general. I would suggest you try to understand the picture of what you want and just formalise each case as it comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example $f(x)=\csc x$, the set of $x$ that is at least $\epsilon\in (0,\pi/2)$ away from any singularity is

$$\bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{Z}}  [\pi n+\epsilon,\pi(n+1)-\epsilon]$$